# Limit of local minimum of function involving zeta function ($e\log x$)

Tags: limits, derivatives, roots, maxima-minima, zeta-functions

I came across the following interesting limit

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\min(x^{n+1}\zeta(x))-\min(x^{n}\zeta(x))\right)$$
for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x\gt1.$ Calculation highly suggests the solution is $e\log x.$

How can we prove this?

Comment: What do you get when replacing $\zeta(x)$ by $1/(x-1)$

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware that they would both have a local minimum there.  Okay that makes sense